# How do I know if my CMS works with the Hosts update to a new php version?

Tags: php, content-management-system, updates, modx

I installed a content management system (in my case Modx Version 2.4.3) on my Host. The php version is right now 5.3.

Now I recieve an email from my host, that php 5.2.,5.3 and 5.4 will be deleted. I am now afraid that my content management system will not work properly anymore.

On the website of Modx it says Modx requires 5.1.2 and higher. 
I am confused what to do and how to be safe that nothing happens with my website.

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: Ask them if their CMS works with any current PHP version.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois If I make a test and change the php version to the newest and it will not work, is it possible to go back to my old php version without any crash?

Comment: As long as your host supports that PHP version, it should work. But you have to move on anyway, since your hosts will not support old PHP versions in the near future.

Comment: Update to the newest version of Modx CMS, it does support current PHP versions (minimum PHP 5.5). https://modx.com/download

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thank you very much!!